# Filtrar registros de um Array de String por palavras separadas por espaços no Java

Tags: java, string, filtro, regex

Como faço para filtrar os registros de um `Array` utilizando no filtro os termos para pesquisa separados por *spaço* ?

Exemplo:

Eu tenho uma `Array` de String com os seguintes registros.

- abridor de garrafa
- caixa com cadeado azul
- cadeado latão 30mm c/03 chaves
- chave de fenda 100mm
- jogo de cadeado c/02 chaves
- pano para limpar pia
- torneira de jardim

No campo do filtro o usuário digitar apenas ***cade chav***, essa pesquisa deve retornar apenas os registros.

- cadeado latão 30mm c/03 chaves
- jogo de cadeado c/02 chaves

Para tentar resolver este problema foi criado uma função com um `for` para ler registro por registro do `Array`. Para cada registro eu tentei utilizar a expressão regular "(cade|chav)" ele filtra os seguintes produtos;

- **caixa com cadeado azul**
- cadeado latão 30mm c/03 chaves amarelo
- **chave de fenda 100mm**
- jogo de cadeado c/02 chaves

Porem os itens em negrito não deve aparecer.

Outra coisa que deve ser levada em consideração o usuário poderá digitar apenas "cadeado", ou "cad latão chaves", ou "azul" ou com uma ou mais palavras no filtro , até ai eu sei que terei que montar a expressão dinamicamente como "(cade|chav)" ou "(cad|latão|chaves)" ou "(azu)" etc.

Se houver outra forma de resolver esse problema em java sem utilizar a expressão regular também será vem vinda.

Comment: A principio diria que terá de fazer um `if(match)` para cada palavra presente no filtro. Basicamente ficaria `if(match("cade") && match("chav")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode se usar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
(?=.*chav)(?=.*cade)
```

E assim por diante para cada palavra.
Eu testei aqui e funcionou: http://www.rubular.com/r/6iCMKiQPIg

Answer (score 1):

O problema provavelmente está na expressão regular que estás a utilizar. Segue um pequeno exemplo (podes ter que fazer alguns ajustes, mas penso que deve funcionar)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Matcher
{
    public static ArrayList<String> getMatchingStrings(ArrayList<String> list, String regex) {

    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    for (String s:list) {
       if (p.matcher(s).matches()) {
          matches.add(s);
       }
    }

   return matches;
   }

   public static String buildRegex(ArrayList<String> listWords) {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       for (String s:listWords) {
           builder.append("(?=.*" + s + "\\w*)");
       }
       builder.append(".+");
       return builder.toString();
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add("abridor de garrafa");
        lista.add("caixa com cadeado azul");
        lista.add("cadeado latão 30mm c/03 chaves");
        lista.add("chave de fenda 100mm");
        lista.add("jogo de cadeado c/02 chaves");
        lista.add("pano para limpar pia");
        lista.add("torneira de jardim");

        ArrayList<String> listWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        listWords.add("cade");
        listWords.add("chav");

        String regex = buildRegex(listWords);

        //ArrayList<String> res = getMatchingStrings(lista, "(?=.*chav\\w*)(?=.*cadea\\w*).+");
        ArrayList<String> res = getMatchingStrings(lista, regex);

        for (String s:res) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
}
```